# Basic counting/combinatorics question

Tags: combinatorics

Consider a set of 100 airline passengers numbered 1 to 100. How many ways to seat them into 100 seats such that even numbered passengers only go to even numbered seats and odd numbered passengers only go to odd
numbered seats.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189)
Please read [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) and the others
there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people
will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation,
and an explanation of your own attempts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By permutation and [Rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) we simply have

$$N=50!\cdot50!$$